# jQuery - Checking if function is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I have my jquery name spaced a certain way in that it is prefixed with NWO.{function-name} to make it a little more organized. So it looks something like this:

```
var NWO = NWO || {}

NWO.Chat = (function() {
   return{
   init : function($objects) {
   console.log('do something');         
   } }
}
}());

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  NWO.Chat.init($('div').find('a.chat'));
});
```

Now the chat element isn't on every page so on certain pages where the chat link doesn't exist I get a  **NWO.Chat is undefined.** I thought for the pages that don't have the chat link I could do something like this to avoid the error.

```
if(jQuery().NWO.Chat){ NWO.Chat.init($('div').find('a.chat')); }
```

or

```
if($.fn.NWO.Chat){ NWO.Chat.init($('div').find('a.chat')); }
```

But neither seems to be working I still get the error. How do I avoid the js error when the chat link isn't on the page. I've been banging my head for hours. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NWO` is not a jQuery plugin so have nothing to do with jQuery, it is a object(looks like a global scope), so you could just do

```
if (NWO && NWO.Chat && typeof NWO.Chat.init == 'function') {
    NWO.Chat.init($('div').find('a.chat'));
}
```

Comment: it will be `undefined`, rather

Comment: @danronmoon what will be undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can use typeof to check if the object is defined or not by comparing it with "undefined"

```
if(typeof NWO.Chat != 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just fix the root of your problem:

```
NWO.Chat = (function() {
   return{
   init : function($objects) {
   console.log('do something');         
   } }
}      //  <<-----------REMOVE THIS CURLY BRACE
}());
```

That extra curly at the end (`}`) is the issue.